# Where is the nuget restore?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

From the [MS documentation on the packages restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore), I read

> You can also restore packages at any time through Visual Studio,
>   `nuget restore`, `dotnet restore`, and xbuild on Mono.

Am I the only one who does not understand **where** to run these commands?

Should it be in the *command line*? in that case in *what folder*? 
Or in *package manager console*?...

I have a cloned project which contains the `projects.json` file but any package installed (as it was copy-pasted from the original project), so now looking how to install packages from the projects.json file...

Comment: In the command line, any folder. `nuget` should be in the path, just like `dotnet` or any other command needed to build a project. `project.json` was abandoned 2-3 years ago by the way. .NET Core projects use the `csproj`, `fsproj` or `vbproj` extensions with new syntax.

Comment: If the tools aren't already in the path, you can start the `Developer Command Prompt` created during Visual Studio's installation. This sets the path, MSBUILD related environment variables etc.

Comment: That's no different than asking how to run `npm` by the way. Make sure it's in the path, then you can run it everywhere. If in doubt, just try it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I launched the Developer Command Prompt, but the command nuget is not recognized

Comment: why do you mean everywhere? that has no sense, I need to restore only packages from a project, not all the packages on the computer...

Answer (score 1):

You can restore packages from the Package Manager Console, or from any command line that has nuget.exe in its path, or even directly through the UI in Visual Studio. Is that what you were looking for?

[image]

Comment: the command nuget is not recognized in the command line, I already tried

Comment: @Serge this means you haven't added its location to the path. Open `Developer Command Prompt` from the start menu. This opens a command prompt and runs a startup script that sets the proper PATH and environment variables

Comment: I launched the `Developer Command Promt for Visual Studio 2017` multiple times, that command prompt does not recognize the nuget command

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with the [nuget.exe CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools), visit [nuget.org/downloads](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and select v4.9.4 to download, open the CMD and use the [restore command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore) to download and install any packages missing from the packages folder like the following screenshot:
[image]